# NodeJS remove event listener for bound function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know the issue I am facing, but not sure how to solve it. Basically I have a `Room` class that stores `Clients`. When they join the room, handlers are attached to them. When they leave, handlers are removed. However, because I am using `bind` (and don't mind changing it if possible) I can't figure out how to call `off` and pass the correct function reference.

```
class Room {
   atttachClientHandlers(client){
      client.on('data', this.handleData.bind(this, client);
   }
   detachClientHandlers(client){
      client.off('data', this.handleData);
   }
   handleData(client, data){
      // do something
   }
}

let client = new Client();
let room = new Room();
room.attachClientHanlders(client); // ok
room.detachClientHandlers(client); // never detaches it
```

I don't see anywhere I can store the handler for this client, or how I can give a name to the function callback.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to do is to store the function reference when it's created, like so:

```
   attachClientHandlers(client){
      this.boundHandleData = this.handleData.bind(this, client);
      client.on('data', this.boundHandleData);
   }
```

Your detach method can then pass this reference to off if the reference exists:

```
detachClientHandlers(client) {
   if (this.boundHandleData) {
      client.off('data', this.boundHandleData);
   }
}
```

Comment: This would only work if only one client ever joined the room.

Comment: Then the instance variable should be a map from client to bound event handler.